# not able to toggle overlay class on div which i hover

Tags: javascript

trying to toggle overlay class from div which i hover , but due to all div have same class js is adding and removing overlay class to all div when i hover on any div ..

> i have a webpage with 10 cards and trying to add overlay class that contain backdrop-filter : blur(4px);

> my code in js is :

```
const cardOverlay = document.querySelectorAll(".card-overlay");
const trendingCard = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

const showOverlay = function () {
  cardOverlay.forEach((card) => card.classList.remove("hidden"));
};

const hideOverlay = function () {
  cardOverlay.forEach((card) => card.classList.add("hidden"));
};

trendingCard.forEach((card) => card.addEventListener("mouseover", showOverlay));

trendingCard.forEach((card) => card.addEventListener("mouseleave", hideOverlay)
);
```

> how can i toggle overlay class on that div only which i hover not all

Comment: Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to handle this would be to pass the card that you are hovering over to the show/hide handlers. Example below:

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

function show(card) {
  card.classList.add('hover');
}

function hide(card) {
  card.classList.remove('hover');
}

cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => show(card));
  card.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => hide(card));
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card.hover {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
```